# Can I tell in code-behind if a popup has been moved relative to its placement target?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, position

I'm working on a WPF project where I have a grid of thumbnails (each thumbnail is a SurfaceButton), and clicking on each thumbnail shows its own popup menu. The popup menu in each case has its 'sibling' photo thumbnail as its placement target. The thumbnail and popup sit alongside each other in a Grid.

I've designed the popup to emulate the kind of popout scrollable menu that you'd find in iOS, complete with a little triangle arrow that points up to the thumbnail the popup relates to (with the popup appearing below the thumbnail).

But, much to my pleasant surprise, if you click on a thumbnail that's at the bottom of the screen, WPF moves the popup above the thumbnail so that it's not off-screen.

This is great, but how can I compare the positions of the two elements and move the arrow accordingly (or hide it and show another), so that the popup above the thumbnail is pointing down to it?

Hope that makes some sense!

I've tried VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset, but that only returns the offset from the element's parent, and these seem to always be 0,0 or 1,1. I've also tried UIElement.PointToScreen, but the numbers I get back from the two elements don't seem to vary when the popup moves.

I'm sure there's a simple solution that I'm missing.

Comment: [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613596.aspx) explains, in great detail, how popup placement works, including how it is positioned when part of the popup goes off-screen. I don't think it answers your question, though. But, there should be a way (similar to what you have tried), to get the screen position of your thumbnail and popup. Maybe post the code you have tried for that?

Comment: Thanks Paul. Already read it though! I breakpointed the click event that shows the popup and checked the following before and after the popup gets moved, and the values are always relatively the same (ie the difference between the thumbnail and the popup): VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(element), element.PointToScreen(new Point(0,0)), element.PointFromScreen(new Point(0,0)). I was also hoping that the popup properties would change, but these remain the same: Placement, PlacementTarget, HorizontalOffset, VerticalOffset. Maybe it's because it hasn't moved until after that method is called?

Comment: Maybe you can try to draw your triangle during VisibilityChanged, Opened or LayoutUpdated events of the popup? In those events, it might have the right position.

Comment: I tried, and I was able to get the popup screen location during the Opened event using popup.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0)).

Comment: What's your popup Placement? I've tried this, but the button and popup are always within 1 pixel of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your popup's actual placement like below

```
// ComboBox for example:
Popup popup = yourcombobox.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", yourcombobox) as Popup;

popup.Opened += (s, a) => {
    // structure inside will be different by your templates
    Dacorator decorator = (s as popup).Child as Decorator;
    Border border = decorator.Child as Border;
    Double y0 = yourcombobox.PointToScreen(new Point(0,0)).Y;
    Double y1 = border.PointToScreen(new Point(0,0)).Y;
    if(y0 > y1) {
        // when shows at the top
        yourcombobox.Background = Brushes.Red;
    } else {
        // when shows at the botttom
        yourcombobox.Background = Brushes.Blue;
    }
};
```

Popup doesn't have it's own size or position, so you have to catch the child's position only when popup is shown.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview